# Implementing minimax by recursively folding

Tags: haskell, artificial-intelligence, fold, minimax

I'm writing a checkers AI for a standard 8*8 drafts version of the game. 
 The state is represented as a lens with lists of Coords representing the pieces on the board. What I am trying to do is follow this pseudo code for a Min-Max search.

```
function minimax(position, depth, maximizingPlayer)
   if depth == 0 or game over in position
        return static evaluation of position

   if maximizingPlayer
         maxEval = -infinity
         for each child of position
              eval = minimax(child, depth-1, False)
              maxEval = max(maxEval, eval)
         return maxEval
   else 
          minEval = +infinity
          for each child of position
              eval = minimax(child, depth-1, true)
              minEval = min(minEval, eval)
         return minEval
```

By my understanding, in my case, `position` would be the `GameState`. So in my program, I would want to call `minimax` again on all children of the `GameState`, which would each just be a `GameState` with a move applied to it. Eventually I would hit depth 0 in which I would return a heuristic I have made a function to calculate. Where I am stuck is how to iterate through each possible GameState after a move. I have a function that calculates all possible moves that can be made from a specific GameState, but I'm stuck on how to iterate through all those moves, calling minimax with the new GameState resulting from the application of every one of the moves.

Going back to the pseudocode, I know that `child` will be a function call  `applyMove` which takes in a Move and the current GameState, and returns a GameState with the new placement of pieces. Each "child" will be a different GameState resulting from different moves. I'm pretty new to Haskell and I know I'll probably need to use a fold for this. But I'm just stuck on how to write it, and I can't find many examples that I can easily relate to my situation. Any advice/tips are greatly appreciated.

The moves list would look something like this: `[[(1,2),(2,3)],[(3,6),(2,7)]]` and the `child` of a `GameState` would be a GameState after the application of a move, e.g

`applyMove [(1,2),(2,3)] gameState`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a few functions already:

```
legalMoves :: Position -> [Move]
applyMove :: Position -> Move -> Position
```

I think your `minimax` would be cleaner with a different signature: instead of taking a Bool to decide whether to maximize or minimize, with different cases for each, it's simpler to always try to maximize, and vary the evaluation function instead, by flipping its sign at each step.

Once you have that, you don't really need to write a fold manually: just `map` recursive calls over each legal move, and glue them together with `maximum` to find the best move for the current player.

```
minimax :: (Position -> Int) -> Int -> Position -> Int
minimax eval 0 pos = eval pos
minimax eval n pos = case legalMoves pos of
  [] -> eval pos
  moves -> maximum . map negate 
       . map (minimax (negate . eval) (n - 1) . applyMove pos) 
       $ moves
```

Note that your specification makes it impossible to decide *what move* is the best, only what score you could get by making the best move. To find the best move, you'll want to make `minimax` return a tuple containing both the score and the move made to get there, or something of that sort.

Comment: thanks a lot! Yeah I was just trying to wrap my head around how to do get the best score, i wasn't really even thinking about how to associate the score with the move. I guess a tuple would be the best way to do this. Would the above code change a lot with that addition?

Comment: Not a lot. You'll change the return values and use `maximumBy snd` or something instead of `maximum`.

Comment: So i tried your code and got some type errors. I think its because my applyMove function is actually of type Move -> Position -> Position. This is consistent throughout my code and used in other functions. Should i change it in my original code or is there another solution?

Comment: You can change `applyMove pos` to `(flip applyMove pos)` to keep the same types. I do think that my order is "better", because it fits better with the kinds of partial application you will tend to do (i.e., apply multiple different moves to the same board). Your version makes it easy to apply the same move to many different boards, which seems a bit less common. It's a pretty subtle difference, though, and there are arguments for your type being better as well.

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much for all your help man, you're a real lifesaver! Your type does seem to fit what i'm trying to do, but unfortunately my professor uses this type throughout the frontend he has set up for us, so it would be unwise of me to change it! Again, thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Naturally, I do encourage you to understand how this solution works. Of course foremost this will aid your education, but also what I've written is pretty clearly not in the style a beginner would use, so if merely copied it will stick out to a professor.

Comment: This is elegant, even if I somewhat dislike the `negate . negate . negate ... . eval` thunks that are being built up. Also, I think `maximum . map negate` can be replaced by `negate . minimum` which should only perform a single negation.

Comment: @amalloy If you're still willing to help me out, how would I go about changing the return values so that it returns the correct move?

Comment: Not really. That belongs in a new question where you explain what you have (a minimax evaluator), what you need (a minimax move selector), how you've tried to get there, and what's tripping you up along the way.